# Codeigniter Email PHP SMPT Error, cannot send mail through Gmail

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am currently trying to send an email or verification email after I've done signing up. The problem is I cannot send a verification through gmail because of this error:

> The following SMTP error was encountered: Unable to send email using
> PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this
> method.

[image]

I've already tried searching for solution here in stackoverflow, but I haven't found any solution that works for my problem.i have also done changing the `smtp_port` to `465` but still, it didn't solve my problem.

I am using Localhost and I configured the `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` on xampp folder.

php.ini

```
[mail function]
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = qwerty@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Send mail

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=qwerty@gmail.com
auth_password=qwertyqwerty
force_sender=qwerty@gmail.com
```

my Code

```
//get user inputs
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$password = $this->input->post('password');

//generate simple random code
$set = '123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$code = substr(str_shuffle($set), 0, 12);

//insert user to users table and get id
$user['email'] = $email;
$user['password'] = $password;
$user['code'] = $code;
$user['active'] = false;
$id = $this->users_model->insert($user);

//set up email
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 587,
    'smtp_user' => 'qwerty@gmail.com', // change it to yours
    'smtp_pass' => 'qwertyqwerty', // change it to yours
    'smtp_timeout' => "",
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE,
    'validate' => FALSE
);

$message =  "
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Verification Code</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>Thank you for Registering.</h2>
                <p>Your Account:</p>
                <p>Email: ".$email."</p>
                <p>Password: ".$password."</p>
                <p>Please click the link below to activate your account.</p>
                <h4><a href='".base_url()."user/activate/".$id."/".$code."'>Activate My Account</a></h4>
            </body>
            </html>
            ";
    
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from($config['smtp_user']);
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject('Signup Verification Email');
$this->email->message($message);

//sending email
if($this->email->send()){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Activation code sent to email');
}
else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->email->print_debugger());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change `php.ini` or `sendmail.ini` to send SMTP. Please make it default.

After I look at your SMTP configuration, You missed a little thing but seems important: crypto protocol.

You can set crypto protocol inside `$config['smtp_host']` like so:

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com'
```

Or you can also try this config:

```
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.googlemail.com";
$config['smtp_port'] = "465";   // if you decided to use 465, then set smtp crypto to ssl, else for example 587, you need to set smtp crypto to tls.
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';  // this is based on your smtp port -> ssl/tls
$config['smtp_timeout'] = "400";
$config['smtp_user'] = "youruser@gmail.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "yourpassword%&^$&$";
$config['validate'] = true;
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

Then assign $config to email library: `$this->load->library('email', $config)`;

Please do check less security (in gmail setting) was: enabled.

Otherwise, you can create email.php as an email config library inside application/config/email.php

just put it there:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.googlemail.com";
$config['smtp_port'] = "465";   // if you decided to use 465, then set smtp crypto to ssl, else for example 587, you need to set smtp crypto to tls.
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';  // this is based on your smtp port -> ssl/tls
$config['smtp_timeout'] = "400";
$config['smtp_user'] = "youruser@gmail.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "yourpassword%&^$&$";
$config['validate'] = true;
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";

?>
```

Then inside your controller you don't need to set up your $config anymore :D, but all you have to do just call `$this->load->library('email');` in controller.

Comment: if I'll deploy this or implement it online, can I still use these codes? will there be a change? thank you, good sir.

Comment: It depends, on your hosting provider. Sometimes, the shared hosting (server) cannot apply SMTP through gmail. You have to double check your hosting provider wether provide it or not. No, you will still use that codes my friend, without any changes. Did you know about SMTP relay? I usually use MAILGUN as my Relay (it's not a free service, tho. Because they have logs, monitor, and also anti-spam for your messages).

Comment: I'll look up on to that today, thank you good sir. I have searched for solution yesterday for hours, and today it finally solved. thanks!

Comment: anytime, my friend. If it still doesn't work, let me know it.

Comment: Hello good sir, I am wondering why the emails are going to the "SPAM" folder. Is there any solution for this? thank you

Comment: hello sir, I uploaded my web app on 000webhost, i am having the same problem..

Comment: @CoderCodes what codeigniter version are u using? and please make sure you shouln't use mail() method, just create a new method like sendmail_now() or something instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WHM please check smtp restriction and disable it, it worked for me. Check Screenshot below:

[image: Smtp Restriction page]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34447609)